# Translation/transliteration help request: 6 characters in seal script on a box holding a medal (Characters identified: 勛六等瑞寶章)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

all -- among a box with some family heirlooms, I've found a lacquer box with a medallion inside. This was from a Russian family that left before 1917, and lived in China and then Japan before immigrating to the USA in 1927. I've got a few ribbons and medals to identify, but despite some competency in modern Mandarin, I've never been able to read seal script at all (except perhaps the second character, 六?). I am eager to crack the mystery of this medal and grateful for any help!
[image]

---

Comment: hi, thanks dROOOze! Your edit is eminently plausible. I can close it or if you put your answer as a solution I can mark it solved.

Comment: @dROOOze, can you submit your transliteration as an answer? A search confirms that this is a Japanese medal, and the images of the medal on wikipedia match that of the medal inside, a Zuihosho or Order of the Sacred Treasure 6th Class.

Comment: @r13, dROOze edited the title but didn't submit an answer, so I don't think you're right. I can answer my own question but I'd like to give credit to dROOOZe for the transliteration.

Comment: I see. My mistake.

Comment: You're welcome to answer your own question - credits are not required. Providing the transcription is a way of helping along the answering process - it's easier to find out the meaning behind a phrase if you know the correct search terminology to use.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to transcription of the seal script by dROOOze, this appears to be an award of the Government of Japan:

勛六等瑞寶章
[Order of the Sacred Treasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_the_Sacred_Treasure), Sixth Class.

Comment: I changed to "transcription" because technically speaking the words these characters represent are Japanese, not Chinese. Feel free to revert the edit.